# Strange Eclipse C++ #define behaviour

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, build-error

*(A case of over relying on an IDE)*

I have some legacy C code that I compile as C++ for the purpose of Unit testing. The C source is C++ aware in that it conditionally *defines* based on environment.

E.g. (`PRIVATE` resolves to `static`):

```
#if!defined __cplusplus
#define PRIVATE1 PRIVATE
#endif
```

...

```
PRIVATE1 const int some_var;
```

The problem is I just can't seem to find out what `PRIVATE1` resolves to or is in C++, the compiler complains of redefinition if I add a declaration but doesn't indicate where?

I have searched my MinGW/gcc include path, the C++ ISO specification and the C++ books available to me has been to no avail.

***Edit:***

Sure I checked the command line and makefiles before posting.

Comment: You should answer your own question and then accept your answer. This has two benefits: first, it makes it clear that to later reader there was an accepted anser; and two, it lets you get some reputation for actually solving your problem...

Comment: @RBerteig - Point taken and answered in the 'right' way. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse C++ managed project's are a little, well stupid!

If a project is declared C++ it still bases it's build on file extension, hence .h file preprocessed as C and not C++ header which pulls in a #define PRIVATE1 from another header file similarly wrapped by:

```
#ifdef __cpluplus.
```

The project is then linked by g++.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing like this in ISO C++ spec. Most likely, `PRIVATE1` (as well as `PRIVATE`) are defined elsewhere in the project. Note that this doesn't need to be a `#define` in an .h file - it can also be defined via compiler switches in the makefile. I'd suggest doing a full grep on the project directory.

Comment: "the C++ ISO specification and the C++ books available to me has been to no avail."

Answer (score 4):

If `PRIVATE1` resolves to `PRIVATE`, and `PRIVATE` resolves to `static`, then `PRIVATE1` resolves to `static`.

Comment: Can't beat that logic...  :-)

Comment: You missed the fact that this define is in `#if !__cplusplus` block. I.e. it doesn't run for a C++ compiler, yet the latter somehow figures out what `PRIVATE` is - so the question is, how it does that.

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely (but not impossible) that they are defined by MinGW itself. Macros defined by the C++ or C implementation should begin with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to look at the preprocessor output.  You didn't post what compiler you are using, but if you check the docs, most have an option to "Preprocess to file" which will create a file with all the macros substituted.  This might be able to help you figure out what is happening.  In Visual Studio you use the /E option (under C/C++->Preprocessor->Generate Preprocessed File) which will turn foo.c into foo.i.  This file will generally be HUGE compared to the original source file, so scroll down to the bottom to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely in C++ it's defined to, well, "private:".

Comment: Mosdt likely not, as the OP's code would then expand to a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "private:" which would be valid

Comment: Then it would need to be part of a class. Since this is compilable in C and C++, it's most likely *not* part of a class.

Comment: It can be part of a struct. The only difference between structs and classes in C++ is that structs default to public, while classes default to private.

Answer (score 0):

Can you declare a function with PRIVATE1? If so, just write a function like so:

```
PRIVATE1 void Foo() {
    // __FUNCSIG__ in Visual Studio, not sure about GCC
    std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl;
}
```